# Dropwizard failed to lazily initialize a collection of role

Tags: java, hibernate, jackson, dropwizard

Using dropwizard 0.9.2 and dropwizard-hibernate 0.9.2, I'm trying to retrieve a collection mapped by `@OneToMany` with hibernate. Unfortunately I'm getting this exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily 
initialize a collection of role: com.ng.Computer.parts, could not 
initialize proxy - no Session
```

I do understand why this is happening (the hibernate session is closed when jackson is trying to serialize the object) but shouldn't the library jackson-datatype-hibernate4 (which is a dependency of dropwizard-hibernate) take care of this for me automatically (reopen a session and materialize the collection) ? If not what is this library doing and how do most dropwizard application solve this (EAGER fetching is not an option) ?

Pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
      <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
      <artifactId>dropwizard-testing</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
      <artifactId>dropwizard-hibernate</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

Model

```
@Entity
public class Computer {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany
    public List<Part> parts;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Part> getParts() {
        return parts;
    }

    public void setParts(List<Part> parts) {
        this.parts = parts;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Part {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Resource:

```
@GET
@UnitOfWork
@Timed
public Response list() {

    Computer computer = computerDAO.findById(1L);

    Response response = Response.ok(computer.getParts()).build();

    return response;
}
```

DAO:

```
public class ComputerDAOImpl extends AbstractDAO<Computer> implements    
ComputerDAO{

    public ComputerDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        super(sessionFactory);
    }

    public Computer findById(Long computationId) {
        Computer computer = get(computationId);
        return computer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

reading the docs, this may be by design:

> Important
>
> The Hibernate session is closed before your resource
> method’s return value (e.g., the Person from the database), which
> means your resource method (or DAO) is responsible for initializing
> all lazily-loaded collections, etc., before returning. Otherwise,
> you’ll get a LazyInitializationException thrown in your template (or
> null values produced by Jackson).

So it appears that your code needs to take care of loading the parts specifically instead of running with this.

Alternatively judging by a quick look at the docs, your issue is the UnitOfWork annotation. This one is responsible for closing the session on you. Reading the docs:

> This will automatically open a session, begin a transaction, call
> findByPerson, commit the transaction, and finally close the session.
> If an exception is thrown, the transaction is rolled back.

In combination with above: If you want to use the UnitOfWork, you must implement lazy loading yourself since the UnitOfWork will otherwise close your session before you get to it. If you don't want to use it, you'll have to handle your transaction differently.

I hope that helps.

Artur